# Non-zero winding number on a space curve implies a linked curve in the zero set?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, knot-link

The following statement has been largely improved from my original post thanks to discussions with @DmitriPanov ad well as the comment from @Wojowu.

> Let $f \colon \mathbb{S}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be real analytic.  Let $C$ be a closed space curve in $\mathbb{S}^3$, which I might need to assume to be unknot.
>    If $f(C) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has a non-zero winding number around $0$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ contains a space curve in $\mathbb{S}^3$ that is linked to $C$.

I consider this as a generalization of Kronecker's existence theorem.  I sketched a plausible argument in my comment to the answer of @DmitriPanov, which I did not check with great care.  The statement and argument is obviously generalizable to other dimensions, using topological degree.

I believe that this result is not new.  So where do I find a reference for this and its higher dimensional versions?

Comment: Let $f$ be the standard projection and $C$ be a flat circle. $f^{-1}(0)$ is a line going through the center of the circle and contains no curve linked to $C$.

Comment: @wojowu this can be fixed by compactify $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{S}^n$.  I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the "winding number" for the loop in $S^2$ around 0? The sphere minus one point is contractible. You need to remove two points to have a nontrivial homotopic invariant.

Comment: @OlegEroshkin You are right.  As I regard $\mathbb{S}^2$ as compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$, I mean the winding number of $f(C)$ in $\mathbb{S}^2 \setminus \infty$.  It is now clarified in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Now the statement is indeed correct. What follows below is and answer to the previous version of the question which I'll keep for the moment.

---

Note that the condition for $f(C)$ to have non-zero winding number around $0$ is more-less empty. Indeed, to fix the winding number of $f(C)$ around $0$ one needs to choose infinity. And for more-less any closed curve $\eta$  in $S^2$ that doesn't pass through $0$ one can choose $\infty \in S^2$ so that the winding number of $\eta$ in $S^2\setminus \infty$ around $0$ is non-zero.

Now, for a concrete set of counter-examples suppose that $f: S^3\to S^2$ is ANY map with non-zero differential at a point $x\in S^3$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$. Then take a small ball $U$ containing $x$ such that $0\notin f(U)$ and a curve $\gamma\subset U$ that projects to a small circle in $S^2$. Choose $\infty\in S^2$ such that $f(\gamma)$ separates $0$ from $\infty$. Then clearly the winding number of $f(\gamma)$ around $0$ is $\pm 1$ but $f^{-1}(0)$ doesn't contain a component linked to $c$.

I can see only one way to fix this. Ask $f$ not to be null-homotopic and ask $C$ to be a full premiage of a point $x\in S^2$ different from $0$ ...

Comment: Thanks!  Do we have a linked curve in $f^{-1}(0) \cap f^{-1}(\infty)$? Although this is not what I am intending to.

Comment: Then, can it be fixed if I work not in $\mathbb{S}^n$, but in the projective space $\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Comment: Concerning your first question I am just saying that $\pi_3(S^2)\cong \mathbb Z$ and if we have a map $\phi: S^3\to S^2$ whose class is equal $n\in \mathbb \pi_3(S^2)\cong \mathbb Z$ then the preimages of two generic points in $S^2$ are links in $S^3$ that have linking number $n$.  Concerning your second question, changing $\mathbb S^n$ to $\mathbb RP^n$ will not make any difference, I don't see how this can be fixed

Comment: Here is another attempt, which I think should work.  If it is, I'll open another question asking for reference.

Let $f$ be a continuous map from 3-ball $\mathbb{B}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $C$ be a closed curve in $\partial \mathbb{B}^3$.  If $f(C)$ has a non-zero winding number around $0$, then the degree theory tell me that $f^{-1}(0)$ has a non-empty intersection with any disk in $\mathbb{B}^3$ bounded by $C$.  If $f$ is moreover real analytic, then $f^{-1}(0)$ contains a path-connected curve that intersects every disk bounded by $C$ (is there a word for this situation?)

Comment: I agree, this modification works

Comment: Wait ... Then there is a simple fix to my question.  Just let $f$ be a map from $S^3$ to $R^2$.  So I panicked too much facing @Wojowu's comment.  I should just compacting the source of $f$, not its target.  I'll update the question and acknowledge you.